# Slicing high-dimensional R arrays with index pairs

Tags: r, arrays, slice

For the matrix `M <- matrix(1:24, nrow = 6, ncol = 4)`, if you want to subset its elements by the index pairs, which are stored as rows in matrix `indexes <- cbind(1:3, 2:4)`, you can do:

```
M[indexes]
# [1]  7 14 21
```

However, I haven't found a simple way to combine index pairs and index grids in slicing higher-dimensional arrays. For example, we have the array `A <- array(1:24, dim = c(2,3,4)`, of which the first dimension should be kept and the last two dimensions are to be subsetted by index pairs. A wordy solution might be:

```
sapply(1:nrow(indexes), \(i) A[, indexes[i,1], indexes[i,2]])
# and structure the matrix back to the array form, if A has even higher dimension.
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    7   15   23
# [2,]    8   16   24
```

But I still want something as clean as

```
A[, indexes[,1], indexes[,2], pairwise = TRUE]  # does it exist?
```

---

*Update 1*
Moreover, I have checked what the Numpy in Python has for their arrays, and I found the following example from this [site](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/02.07-fancy-indexing.html):

```
X = np.arange(12).reshape((3, 4))
X
# array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
#        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
#        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])

row = np.array([0, 1, 2])
col = np.array([2, 1, 3])
X[row, col]
# array([ 2,  5, 11])

X[row[:, np.newaxis], col]  # broadcasting rules
# array([[ 2,  1,  3],
#        [ 6,  5,  7],
#        [10,  9, 11]])
```

The python version of the solution is quite simple and clear. In the same spirit,

Comment: I guess I'm confused by your use of 'pairwise', are you looking for output similar to `for (i in 1:dim(A)[3]) {print(t(as.matrix(A[,,i]))) }` ?

Comment: It is not possible to do it like that, because that kind of syntax would conflict with that of selecting elements along each axis, and the generic function signature for the `[` method already has a boolean `drop` argument which would prevent adding this. If you want this kind of function and you want it to be fast, you'd have to implement it yourself with e.g. Rcpp.